# Creating a login in javascript - array comparison

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, authentication

I have a login box using a simple javascript login comparing usernames and passwords, before you all start I know about the security issues in using javascript for authentication. Here is the code

```
function validate() {
    var un = document.getElementById("usern").value;
    var pw = document.getElementById("pword").value;
    var valid = false;

    var unArray = ["markwalt", "jongossy", "lisacain", "jenndemp"];
    var pwArray = ["mark1234", "flomaygo", "lisa1234", "jenny1234"];
    var fnArray = ["Mark Walters", "Jonathan Goss", "Lisa Cain", "Jenny Dempsey"];

    for (var i=0; i <unArray.length; i++) {
        if ((un == unArray[i]) && (pw == pwArray[i])) {
            valid = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (valid) {
        alert ("Login was successful");
        document.getElementById("mandatory1").value = un;
    }
    else {
        alert("Invalid Username and/or Password! Please try again. You will not be able to submit this form without a successful login")
        document.getElementById("pword").value = "";
        document.getElementById("usern").value = "";
        document.getElementById("usern").focus();
    }
}
```

At the moment if the login is successful I'm posting the username to a hidden field which is then being used by a piece of a software. How do I associate the names in fnArray with the other correct username & password so that I can then grab associated full name and post that to the hidden field "mandator1" instead?

Comment: why does fnArray has only one big string in it ?

Comment: I know i wrote at the top of the question that i understood. This isn't an issue for what this is being used for. Thank you

Comment: No Adham, sorry my mistake, only just realised i've missed out a whole load of "" each side of the names. Thanks

Comment: I've tried them all and they all work. so many thanks. I've only been using javascript for a couple of months so occassionaly i need a bit of a push to find a solution for something that might seem simple. Again thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a variable for full name, and set it if you have the valid user:

```
var fn = "";

/* ... */

valid = true;
fn = fnArray[i];

/* ... */

document.getElementById("mandatory1").value = fn;
```

**Note:** Actually you can check validity later on using `fn`. If it is empty string, then no user was logged in. This makes it have same purpose as `valid`, and more.

Comment: Found this one the easiest to understand and liked you're explanation on checking validity against fn as well. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can get the index of the correct user

```
var unArray = ["markwalt", "jongossy", "lisacain", "jenndemp"];
var pwArray = ["mark1234", "flomaygo", "lisa1234", "jenny1234"];
var fnArray = ["Mark Walters, Jonathan Goss, Lisa Cain, Jenny Dempsey"];
var index = 0;
for (var i=0; i <unArray.length; i++) {
    if ((un == unArray[i]) && (pw == pwArray[i])) {
        valid = true;
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

now you can access the correct data using

```
unArray[index]; 
// and so on for other arrays
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
function validate() {
    var un = document.getElementById("usern").value;
    var pw = document.getElementById("pword").value;
    var valid = -1;

    var unArray = ["markwalt", "jongossy", "lisacain", "jenndemp"];
    var pwArray = ["mark1234", "flomaygo", "lisa1234", "jenny1234"];
    var fnArray = ["Mark Walters","Jonathan Goss","Lisa Cain","Jenny Dempsey"];

    for (var i=0; i <unArray.length; i++) {
        if ((un == unArray[i]) && (pw == pwArray[i])) {
            valid = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (valid != -1) {
        alert ("Login was successful");
        document.getElementById("mandatory1").value = fnArray[valid];
    }
    else {
        alert("Invalid Username and/or Password! Please try again. You will not be able to submit this form without a successful login")
        document.getElementById("pword").value = "";
        document.getElementById("usern").value = "";
        document.getElementById("usern").focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you can say what you didi?

Comment: @ibu: just get the key where username and password matches and check the key is valid and fetch the name with referring the key to fnArray.

Comment: yes i understood what you meant, but to why right long code without explanation or any comment.

Comment: @lbu: pal, if you diff the original code the op has posted, you can then see i have changed only simple three lines.

Answer (score 0):

set mandatory1 when the login is successful based on i (in the for loop)